# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FromSession'

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy some files from remote servers to local with the following:

```
function getfiles {

& C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\stores\getfiles.ps1
  }

function create {
New-Item -ItemType directory -Force -Path C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\stores
}
#####copy files to local#####

$computer = Get-Content C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\stores\computers.txt
$computer | ForEach-Object {
$session=new-pssession -computername $_ -credential (Import-Clixml "mycredentials.xml")
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock ${function:create}
Copy-Item -path "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\stores\getfiles.ps1" -destination "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\stores\getfiles.ps1" -recurse -ToSession $session 
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock ${function:getfiles}
Copy-Item -path "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\stores\UK*" -Destination "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\stores" -recurse -FromSession $session
Get-PSSession -ComputerName $_ -Credential (Import-Clixml "mycredentials.xml") | Disconnect-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
}
```

For some strange reason the

```
Copy-Item -path "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\stores\UK*" -Destination "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\stores" -recurse -FromSession $session
```

Stopped working with the following error:

```
Copy-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FromSession'.
At line:20 char:122
+ ... "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\stores" -recurse -FromSession $sessio ...
+                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Some notes:

1. The drives on both servers exist, not the bug mentioned in couple of topics.
2. The getfiles.ps1 executes as expected and it is for file creation.

Comment: Looks like it's because of the `*` in the source path provided, [fixed in the latest release of PowerShell 7](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/15525)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen added `-filter UK*` and it worked. Strange why it was working fine until one moment. Thank you!

Comment: basically the runtime fails to resolve `"C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\stores\UK*"` to any existing local path (as expected), and as a result of failed wildcard expansion, a bug (unrelated to your use case) is triggered that prevents the file system provider from reporting back to the runtime that `-FromSession` is a valid parameter. Moving the wildcard to the `-Filter` parameter and supplying an exact path without wildcards means no attempts at resolving wildcards are attempted or fail = no bug triggered either.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen can you post the first comment as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a long-standing bug that was [recently fixed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/15525/files).

Basically, whenever the `-Path` argument contains wildcard expressions (eg. `*`) that *fail to resolve to any local file system items*, the runtime will skip generation of dynamic parameters for the target provider (in this case the `FileSystem` provider).

`-ToSession` and `-FromSession` happens to be dynamic provider parameters.

As you've already found, moving the wildcard to the `-Filter` parameter works:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\stores" -Filter 'UK*' -Destination "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\stores" -Recurse -FromSession $session
```